# Add Width to #wpcontent in wp-admin.css

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Does anybody know a way to specify a width for the CSS style id, #wpcontent, in the admin area without modifying the core files? I'd like to expand the width for my plugin setting page. I just need to change `#wpcontent{height:100%}` to `#wpcontent { height:100%; width: 100%; }`.

According to [this page](http://millionclues.com/wordpress-tips/how-to-add-css-styles-to-wordpress-admin/), it seems another CSS file needs to be embedded. But if you can show an easy way, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to import external files.

```
$width = 'width: 100%;';
echo '<style type="text/css">
    #wpcontent {
        height:100%;
        ' . $width . '
    }
    #footer {
        ' . $width . '
        color: #777;
        border-color: #DFDFDF;
    }           
</style>';
```

Also, instead of `stripos()`, I would use $_GET,

```
if ($_GET['page'] == PLUGINPAGESLUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, it wasn't that hard to do and it seems to be okey to have a separate css file although it looks a bit heavy thing for such a small task.

I followed what this page says: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

### main plugin file:

```
define('PLUGINPAGESLUG', 'mypluginpageslug');
add_action('admin_head', 'Plugin_Custom_CSS');
function Plugin_Custom_CSS() {
    if (stripos($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?page=' . PLUGINPAGESLUG) !== false) 
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . plugins_url('/css/myadminpage.css', __FILE__). '">';
}
```

### css\myadminpage.css

```
#wpcontent { height:100%; width: 100%; }
```

That was it.